# Sitefinity 11 - FrontEndLoginPageUrl not working

Tags: sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity 11, I have setup **FrontEndLoginPageUrl** to my page named login, in **Administration » Settings » Advanced » Project » DefaultSite**, but when I go to checkout it redirects to default login page **/Sitefinity/Authenticate/OpenID/login**.

[image]

I searched a lot but no solution was found for this.
I found this link https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/In-some-cases-Sitefinity-redirects-frontend-users-to-backend-login-screen here are few other steps, but I can not see the field **AuthenticateOnFrontendLoginPage** on the  **Advanced Settings > Security** section.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is multisite enabled? 
If yes click on the top left (SitefinityWebApp) -> Manage Sites -> Actions (on the site you want to change) -> Properties -> Configure your frontend login page there.

Multisite login setup: https://docs.sitefinity.com/frontend-login-page#multisite-frontend-login-page-configuration

Single Site login setup(the instructions you followed):  https://docs.sitefinity.com/frontend-login-page#single-site-frontend-page-configuration